# Dell Latitude E6520 with Monitor Dell P2311H cannot get 1600*1200 resolution on the screen

Tags: windows-7, dell-latitude

I have Windows 7 (32 bit) OS with VGA card NVIDIA 4200M I cannot get the 1600*1200 for graphical work and it an error appears that the display doesn't support this resolution, BUT my colleges have the same laptop with Windows XP OS and with the same specs and with the same screen it support the required resolution.
I have checked the driver and it's updated.

Comment: Is your monitor connected via VGA cable or via DVI?

Answer (score 0):

Either the OS, the card, the screen itself, or the driver, is not the same.

Given your parameters above, I'd guess the laptop isn't actually identical to the others.

Check with a tool that can give you this sort of info, like Piriform's [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy).

**EDIT**: Incidentally, Windows 7 may not have the same drivers as XP, so this is something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to  the [documentation](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-p2311h/pd)Dell P2311H display supports a native resolution of 
1920 x 1080 at 60 Hz. Even if you get the monitor to display at the 1600*1200 resolution the image will be downscaled and rather distorted

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Dell has monitor drivers available for most monitors (including that one).  Install the driver for that monitor from Dell's site.
2. Depending on the video card chipset, you may need updated drivers for the display adapter.  I had to actually go to Intel's site to get a driver that worked best for my 6520.